# Where does Visual Studio 2015 display error indicators in the solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am checking out Visual Studio 2015 RC. Where does Visual Studio 2015 display error indicators in the solution? If I am in a cs file which compiles fine but the the solution has compile errors, how do I find out by glancing at the IDE without opening windows? Looking for something similar to R#'s solution wide analysis indicator or Redgate's NET Demon bar (in VS 2013).

Comment: I suspect you have simply not enabled that panel,for some reason when I install VS I find the error list is not enabled and I have to enable it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *exact* thing you're looking for isn't available in Visual Studio 2015 out of the box. But there's a few options.

### Built in: Error List

The Error List has been enhanced, and it's more dynamic now due to Roslyn, so you can see warnings & errors as you code (without having to recompile).

You have more control over what's shown too; you can filter by Entire Solution, Open Documents, Current Project or Current Document, as well as combinations of IntelliSense or Build feedback:

[image]

If you pin the Error List somewhere always visible, then you will get some of the real-time feedback you want.

### Productivity Power Tools Extension

Microsoft's [Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d) extension for Visual Studio has a **Solution Explorer Errors** feature that gives visual feedback in the Solution Explorer for warnings and errors, at all levels (file, project, solution).

It's directly linked to the Error List and the options you've selected in there. It's basically a real-time projection of the Error List onto the Solution Explorer:

[image]

The page for the VS2013 version of the extension has more information and pictures if you want to look at their docs before making your choice: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace (it comes with a lot of other features, but you can always disable what else you don't want)

### Other options

Outside of the in-built or Microsoft options, you have the commerical **ReSharper**, and any other extensions that people make available. I'm a big ReSharper fan, so I'm not up to date with the other options right now.

Comment: I use ReSharper but its solution wide analysis gives many false postitive errors in asp.net mvc apps that makes it useless. I will be content for now with the ones mentioned.

Comment: Is it the web.config file or view markup files that ReSharper gives bad errors for? You might be able to ignore them for that particular file or type, so then you can happily use Solution-wide Analysis again.

Comment: It's in controllers and views. views have code in them so I would rather not exclude them. I don't think R# checks config files.

Comment: ReSharper checks web.config files. If you look at ReSharper options > Code Inspection > Inspection Severity, you can see the supported types in there.

Comment: Ok but I don't depend on R# to check my config files. First web.config is not a file I touch on a regular basis. Second.. .NET will quickly find any errors in it. An ASP.NET app won't even launch if web.config has a problem.

Comment: Regarding the Productivity Power Tools I am unable to see any errors in my solution explorer window and I do have the option selected in the Options for Power Tools. Do you know of any other conflicts with this? IN addition, when I attempt to filter the Solution Explorer by files with errors in them I get nothing, even though I've purposely made errors in over 20 files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the error list, if it is not visible already

Click View > Error List

Comment: The error list panel is not the type of indicator iam looking for.  I went through a whole discussion about this panel in the first answer here.  I guess you haven't read it.  Please read all the answers before answering